# constantly updating time in a UITableView footer?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to display active, constantly updating time from another time zone in a UITableView footer. Is this even possible/the most sensible way of doing it? I may be overthinking this.

Eg:

---

Tableviewcell A

---

Tableviewcell B

---

Current time in London: 8:45 <---updates continuously without requiring the user to refresh the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your UITableView tableFooterView property to a custom view (containing a UILabel) and keep a reference to it, you can then use a repeating NSTimer with an interval of 1 second and update the UILabel text according to the current london time.

Comment: I can support this solution. I've done it the same way. You only have to keep your eyes on the NSTimer to stop/start the timer if your view is changing or again coming up. I had some trouble on this issue first.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a special subclass of UIView inside with a Timer.

This timer would refresh the time (inside a UILabel?).

And put this subclass as the footer of your UITableView :-)

Try & say us if you have any problem.